# Django select_related the join table only for a many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-orm, manytomanyfield, django-select-related

I have a Django application with a model `A` with a `ManyToManyField` `bees` to model `B`:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    bees = models.ManyToManyField("B", related_name="aas", blank=True)

    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.TextField()


class B(models.Model):

    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
```

For one view, when I select a bunch of A's I also need the ids of their B's. The default where Django queries the related B's for each A individually is too slow, so I use `select_related`.

If I do `A.objects.select_related('bees')` Django selects the full `B` models:

```
SELECT ("app_a_bees"."from_a_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_from_a_id", 
       "app_b"."id", 
       "app_b"."field1", 
       "app_b"."field2", 
FROM "app_b" 
INNER JOIN "app_a_bees" ON ("app_b"."id" = "app_a_bees"."to_b_id") 
WHERE "app_a_bees"."from_a_id" IN (... list of A ids ...)
```

But I only need their id values, so I only need to select the `app_a_bees` join table to get them, not the `B` model table.

I tried `A.objects.select_related('bees__id')` (I also tries `'bees_id'`) but Django doesn't like that, individual fields cannot be prefetched in this way.

I have also tried `A.objects.select_related(Prefetch("bees", queryset=B.objects.all().only("id"))`, but that still joins to the `B` table to select the `id` field, which Django already has from the join table.

Is there any way to prefetch just the join table for my `A` objects?

Comment: Can you please share your models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sure. It's just a simplified test model derived from my actual application.